# How to only allow a custom subset of plugins in Firefox?

Tags: windows, firefox, plugins, flash-player, browser-plugin

I keep the Firefox setting **`plugin.scan.plid.all`** set to **`false`**, since too many programs automatically add their own invasive Firefox plugins to the Windows registry whenever they are installed and/or updated.

Unfortunately, this also disables the Adobe Flash plugin, which my users require.

**Is there a way to allow PLID scanning for only a custom subset of plugins**, e.g. the subset of Firefox plugins that contains only the Adobe Flash plugin?

**Alternatively, is there any way to set the default status of plugins to disabled**, such that all plugins are scanned and show up in the Firefox plugins list but disabled by default, and then define a subset of those plugins that will be enabled by default?

---

Yes, Firefox has had hard-coded special support [in [nsPluginHost.cpp](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/plugins/base/nsPluginHost.cpp#2430)] for the Acrobat, Java, Quicktime, and Windows Media Player plugins since 2002 [see [BugZilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=133282)], but this question is not concerned with those plugins.

And yes, I have tried copying the Adobe Flash plugin .dll to the `plugins` folder, but Firefox does not recognize it, even though the other plugins in that folder are loaded normally. 
 And in any case, even if it worked, copying the Adobe Flash plugin .dll to the `plugins` directory *every time* the Adobe Flash Player is updated is not an acceptable long-term solution.

Now you ask, why not just patch the source to add in whatever feature you want? Because I would rather use the precompiled binaries than have to compile my own version of Firefox every time a security fix is released.

Comment: Looks like there's a separate preference for the Acrobat plugin as described in the [MozillaZine Knowledge Base](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Plugin_scanning#Related_preferences), so you may be able to enable scanning just for it.

Comment: `flash != acrobat`

Comment: Yeah, I know. `pref("plugin.scan.Acrobat", "5.0");`